# Form post but do not reload the page

Tags: ajax, forms, razor, webmatrix

I am stuck in this like I have never before.

My situation : I am making a shopping cart. When user click "Add" button, it posts the form and in the server side i.e inside if(IsPost){....}, corresponding item gets added to the the the cart table in my database.

Everything is fine, except it reloads the page and scrolls back to top. With a little research, I got to know that may be Ajax could help. Then I created a new .cshtml page add-to-cart.cshtnl. Now my current page doesn't reload but it opens add-to-cart.cshtml which is not how I wanted. Now I even tried to learn AJAX and try doing things looking at examples. Nothing helps. Please help!

Here is what my code looks like : P.S I am using razor in webmatrix.

```
<form method="post" id="productForm" action="~/add-to-cart.cshtml">
<input ............"Input Something.............../>
<button type="submit" id="add-button" >ADD</button>
</form>
```

At my add-to-cart.cshtml, I don't have anything on the UI. It just processes data.I don't want that page to ever load. It looks something like this:

```
ifIsPost(){ 
............ADD item to the cart table of database..............
}
```

Now I am convinced, AJAX is my solution but how????
Please don't give me incomplete answers. I have already wasted 3 days in it :/

Comment: You can post a form through ajax. It does not reload the page. Refer http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Yes I know that and I have visited that site already. You didn't read my entire question. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$('#productForm').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: $(this).attr('action'),
       data : $(this).serialize(),
       success : function(response) {
           //write your code here
       },
       error : fucntion(response) {
           //write your code here
       }
   });
});
```

Put this script into `<script>` tag.

Note: Don't forgot to include jquery in your page.

Comment: Thanks that helped!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the complete working solution :

```
$(function () {
            $('#productForm').submit(function (ev) {
                var frm = $(this);    
                $.ajax({
                    type: frm.attr('method'),
                    url: frm.attr('action'),
                    data: frm.serialize(),
                    success: function (data) {
                        //Do What Ever You Wanna Do
                    }
                });
                ev.preventDefault();
            });
        });
```